# CUPS printing of PDF files

Tags: cups

How can I tell the `lpr` command (CUPS) that my file is actually a PDF?

`lpr file.pdf`

won't print anything.

Comment: What programming language are you using? As per the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/), Stack Overflow is intended for programming-related questions. If you have a question about general computer use, you should ask it on [Super User](http://superuser.com/), or if it's about Unix/Linux, on [Unix/Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You are correct, I apologize. This should be moved to Unix/Linux - can anyone with proper privileges to this please? Thanks. [I'm working with python-cups, but I fail to print on the command line as well]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this really the CUPS-based `lpr`, or is it a remnant of another spooling system which was not removed before installing CUPS?

Check it by running `ldd $(which lpr)` and see if there is any reference to libcups.

Also, the complete command should be:

```
lpr -P printername file.pdf
```

For a correctly and completely installed CUPS you'd not need to tell it the file type you send to print. It will "auto-type" the input, and apply the right conversion filters to make it digestable by the target printer.